# Jira Rest API and maxResults

Tags: curl, jira, jira-rest-api

I've already searched a lot of pages and I have not found any valid solution to display all values from the following query:

```
curl -u $c_user:$c_pass -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://jira.mysite.eu/rest/api/2/search?jql=project%20%3D%20%22My%20IT%20Project%22%20AND%20status%20%3D%20%22To%20Acceptance%22
```

it works very well, but displays only the first **50 results**. I tried different ways, but none of them work as it should, for example:

```
curl -u $c_user:$c_pass -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://jira.mysite.eu/rest/api/2/search?jql=project%20%3D%20%22My%20IT%20Project%22%20AND%20status%20%3D%20%22To%20Acceptance%22&startAt=0&maxResults=500
```

or

```
curl -u $c_user:$c_pass -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://jira.mysite.eu/rest/api/2/search?maxResults=500?jql=project%20%3D%20%22My%20IT%20Project%22%20AND%20status%20%3D%20%22To%20Acceptance%22
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check your 'jira.search.views.default.max' Jira property, 
From the docs for search 'maxResults':
"the maximum number of issues to return (defaults to 50). The maximum allowable value is dictated by the JIRA property 'jira.search.views.default.max'. If you specify a value that is higher than this number, your search results will be truncated."
https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/?_ga=2.202487186.20999375.1527529030-971685556.1498061141#api/2/search-search